# How to navigate between test and test subject in PyCharm if function name starts with "_"?

Tags: pycharm, code-navigation

If I have a function "baa" and a corresponding unit test "test_baa", I am able to use `Ctr+Shift+T` to navigate between test and test subject, also see

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/navigating-between-test-and-test-subject.html

However, if I rename the function "baa" to "_baa" and the test to "test__baa", the navigation does not work any more. Keeping the original name "test_baa" also did not work.

=> How can I navigate between test and test subject in PyCharm, if the function name starts with "_"?

[image]

foo.py:

```
def _baa():
    return 1
```

test_foo.py:

```
from foo import _baa


def test__baa():
    result = _baa()
    assert result == 1
```

=> Error:

[image]

Comment: Are you using pytest or unittest?

Comment: pytest  (more characters to be able to comment)

Comment: Notice the comment in [pytest](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/pytest.html): *"Although Go To Test Subject and Go To Test commands of the context menu are not supported for pytest, you can navigate to the tested code in Car.py by using the Go To Declaration"* This works only for module level functions, and apparently they have to follow an exact naming syntax: `functionname_test` any other combination won't work. It's likely a bug that the private leading underscore isn't considered even in that limited scenario.

Comment: The docs suggest using `Ctrl+B`, likely because given the restrictions on naming conventions it was never going to be useful given that you can't name lower-case test functions after camel-case Classes+methods names. (I'm on a slightly older PyCharm version and can't test this any further...)